# ArcMap 10.3 fails to export a clipped image from a mosaic dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, arcgis-10.3, mosaic-dataset

ArcMap 10.3 fails to export a clipped image form a mosaic dataset.

I have the following mosaic dataset, I have used Image analysis to clip apart of it based on a polygon, but the issue here is that when I try to export it every time my workstation freezes and stops working

The area of the polygon is about 996,648 Km2 and my workstation is very powerful, I don’t know if it’s a bug or what in this tool.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now the ArcMAP starts to count but the machine freeze at 1% or more but never reaches 100% , what might be the issue here?

Comment: have you tried with "copy raster" or "clip" tool after disabling "background processing? Have you tried with a compression ?

Comment: Hi radouxju, Yes I did, but it still fails, the background processing is disabled, I have tried JPEG compression with 75 Quality but nothing helps